# pagination logic without offset usage by max id as pagination filter condition for php codeigniter framework

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2, php-7

i see there are few methods we can apply pagination, an one of it is utilizing CI pagination library that generates links for us to navigate.

being main logic centered to

- fetching limited data relevant to display

  and iterate as move across pagination links.. here is my model logic without offset usage(for performance to use primary key `id`)

using limit, maxid of last run ,usertype; so next run should on rows greaterthan supplied id.

in controller say i am collecting results to data["results"] as

```
$data["results"] = $this->ressults_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"],$maxidvalue,$usertype);
```

in model.

```
public function fetch_data($limit,$maxid,$usertype) {
      $date = date('Y-m-d');

      $this->db->limit($limit);
      $this->db->order_by('post_date', 'DESC');
      $this->db->select('id,title');
      if ($usertype == 1)
      {$query = $this->db->get_where('titles',array('id >' => $id,'expiry_date >' => $date));}
      else
      {$query = $this->db->get_where('titles',array('id >' => $id,'expiry_date >' => $date,'visibility'=>'All'));}


      if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        { return $query->result();  }
      return array();
    }
```

**challenge** how to collect and pass the maxid recursively  for pagination to work.

appreciate some pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

i have used session variable maxid that stores the max value and feeds the fetch_data method as parameter after every result display.

```
foreach ($data["results"] as $row) {
if ( $this->session->get_userdata('sessiondata')['maxid'] > $row->id)
$this->session->unset_userdata('maxid');
$this->session->set_userdata('maxid',$row->id);
echo "new value".$this->session->get_userdata('sessiondata')['maxid'];
}
```

please post if you have any better solution to solve this.

Thanks!